# How to run through a bash script loop in separate terminals

Tags: bash, shell

I need to run a bunch of services in separate terminal windows.
Ideally, there would be a script to do this. However, I'm unsure
about what way is the most elegant/safest/most portable/coolest/best.

The script would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

commonPath="~/Documents/myServices"
for x in service1 service2 service3; do 
  gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'cd $commonPath/$x;make;$SHELL'
  done
```

However, **this doesn't work** , as the variables $commonPath and $x
are not exported into the new gnome-terminal. What is the best way
to solve the problem?

Comment: This is what "export" is for.  `export commonPath="~/Documents/myServices"`.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Not sure that the environment will be propagated to the shell started from the Terminal; see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412295/how-are-environment-variables-defined-in-a-gnome-terminal-session). It could well be that Gnome starts its processes with a fresh environment.

Comment: (1) You are using single quotes in your `gnome-terminal` command, which inhibit variable expansion. (2) I find it somewhat confusing that you talk about bash scripts, and then start the gnome terminals with plain POSIX shell scripts. (3) Since you use double-quotes in the definition of `commonPath`, tilde-expansion does not occur.

Comment: See also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468685/how-to-pass-variables-to-gnome-terminal-command).

Answer (score 0):

So may problem with this.

1. When you are starting a new Shell, you are losing exported item right away. If you want them to be appear in next shell, at least you have to add the variable in the `rc` file
2. Single quote will not process variable it would have to be double quote. i.e.

```
#gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'cd $commonPath/$x;make;$SHELL'
gnome-terminal -- sh -c "cd $commonPath/$x;make;$SHELL"
```

And for your problem, probably better solution would be

```
commonPath="~/Documents/myServices"
for x in service1 service2 service3; do 
 make -C $commonPath/$x &
done
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants to have different terminal windows, so that he can follow in parallel the output of the individual `make` commands.

Comment: Yes, they're separate services and need to run in separate terminal windows. That's what the problem is about.

Comment: Then you can redirect output in separate files and tail the files separately in separate window